# How to get my birthday present in Guild Wars?

Tags: guild-wars

My character gets 1 year old soonish. How do I get the birthday present?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Patience =)... They just show up in your inventory on your player's birthday.

Comment: And if you keep your character long enough, you'll get another one on your next birthday :)

Answer (score 11):

Your birthday present will appear in the first empty spot in your inventory the first time you log in with that character on your characters birtday.

If your inventory is full on the birthday of your character, you will receive the gift the next time you log in with at least one space free.

Answer (score 0):

As people said in the answers above, the present appears in your inventory on your character's birthday. I suggest creating as many characters as you can (fill all your available slots) to get more presents - every character will get their own gift on the anniversary.